# Python Flask LDAP connect user with sAMAccountname

Tags: python, flask, ldap

I am developing a web app and trying to connect our company users through our AD using there sAMAccountname as they are used to. So far, I can connect users with their DistinguishedName but I can't find the way to do it with the sAMAccountname, any clue ?

in my **init.py** I have :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'connection_to_db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'

# The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with.
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'sAMAccountName'

app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'] = 'connection_to_ldap'
app.config['LDAP_PROTOCOL_VERSION'] = 3
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

and in my models.py I have :

```
def get_ldap_connection():
    conn = ldap.initialize(app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'])
    return conn

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
 
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
 
    @staticmethod
    def try_login(username, password):
        conn = get_ldap_connection()
        res = conn.simple_bind_s(
            'CN=%s,DC=example,DC=com' % username,
            password
        )
        # conn.unbind()
        print(res)
 
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
 
    def is_active(self):
        return True
 
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
 
    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Thanks in advance